# Invalid syntax error on print command in django-crontab

Tags: python, django

I am getting an invalid syntax error on a valid Python 3 print command in django-crontab:

```
python3 manage.py crontab add

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/__init__.py", line 124, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 821, in _gcd_import
    loader.load_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 436, in load_module
    return self._load_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 141, in decorated
    return fxn(self, module, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 342, in _load_module
    exec(code_object, module.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django_crontab/management/commands/crontab.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django_crontab.crontab import Crontab
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 436, in load_module
    return self._load_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 141, in decorated
    return fxn(self, module, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 330, in _load_module
    code_object = self.get_code(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 413, in get_code
    dont_inherit=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django_crontab/crontab.py", line 97
    print(u'Currently active jobs in crontab:')
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have added 'django_crontab' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings, and I have specified the jobs using:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('0 0 * * *', 'app.cron.update_entries'),
    ('0 * * * *', 'app.cron.delete_queries')
]
```

What is going on folks, it is as if it's being run as Python 2 code?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your involved code?

Comment: I added the code from settings.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `print` that is invalid, it's the `u` prefix. That wasn't supported in Python 3.2. You should upgrade to at least 3.3.